# System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException to consume WCF Rest Service from Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am a fan of Microsoft. I am beginner in windows phone app development. I have faced a big problem, i can't over come it for few days. When i try to connect to wcf service from windows phone 8 (vs 2013 pro 64 bit) an exception arises such as-

> An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

```
My Code- private void GetData()  
{  
ADARA.WsBankUltimusCoreService.InterfaceToFetchServiceClient clientForTesting = new       ADARA.WsBankUltimusCoreService.InterfaceToFetchServiceClient();       clientForTesting.EnquiryAccountSummuryCompleted += new           EventHandler<WsBankUltimusCoreService.EnquiryAccountSummuryCompletedEventArgs>      (TestCallback); clientForTesting.EnquiryAccountSummuryAsync("0000217392", "1",               "mobilebanking", "QmkAc", "json");  
}  

private void TestCallback(object sender,       WsBankUltimusCoreService.EnquiryAccountSummuryCompletedEventArgs e)  
{  
var test = e.Result;  
}
```

Additional information:

1. Emulator can't access internet.
2. Network type- Static IP (not DHCP).
3. Emulator displays IP(Adapter-2)- 169.254.143.163.
4. Status of vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch) is- Unidentified network.
5. IP of WCF Service- 192.168.20.233
6. IP of Client - 192.168.20.234
   used tools-
   Service- VS 2012
   Client- VS 2013 pro + Win phone 8.0

Both Client and Server exist in a same LAN, so wcf service is remote(not local) from client.

Really i am in trouble, please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Don't know much about the problem but 169.254.x.x is the IP which is assigned by Windows as a fall-back when you have configured DHCP but no DHCP server can be reached. Is your Emulator network configured correctly?

Comment: Have you verified the wcf address, using visual studio wcf test client maybe?